# Supertypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Apologies in advance if I use the wrong terminology here.

What is the idiomatic way in Haskell to generalize two or more types so that you can defer pattern-matching against them while avoiding boilerplate code?

To give a concrete example: In my application I want to pass on possible errors that can happen during the execution. These errors are from a different module, so I don't directly control them:

```
data ErrorCatA = WTFError String | OMGError String
data ErrorCatB = BadError Int | TerribleError Float
```

Now I want to pass some form of supertype of these error categories on so I can handle them like this:

```
handleError :: GenericError -> IO ()
handleError err =
    putStrLn $ case err of
        WTFError s -> "WTF?! " ++ s
        OMGError s -> "OMG?! " ++ s
        BadError i -> if i > 5 then "Really bad" else "Not that bad"
        TerribleError f -> "Terrible! " ++ show f
```

*Is this possible?*

I got closest by creating a wrapper type like this:

```
data GenericError = CatA ErrorCatA | CatB ErrorCatB
class GError a where
    wrap :: a -> GenericError

instance GError ErrorCatA where
    wrap = CatA

instance GError ErrorCatB where
    wrap = CatB
```

By doing this I can wrap all errors easily, as in

`handleError $ wrap $ WTFError "Woopsie"`

but I would need to change `handleError` to match against `CatA (WTFError s)` etc.

Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way of dealing with a scenario like this?

Comment: Use `Either`?  It's equivalent to your `GenericError` type, and then just write your `GError` class to target that instead.  `type GenericError = Either ErrorCatA ErrorCatB`; `instance GError ErrorCatA where wrap = Left`; `instance GError ErrorCatB where wrap = Right`.  Alternatively, you can write `data GenericError = WTFError' String | OMGError' String | BadError' Int | TerribleError' Float` and then just write your `wrap` function appropriately and you can pattern match on those constructors instead.

Comment: I didn't want to make the question even longer so I didn't mention `Either`, but I want to have a solution that works with any number of different errors, also I don't think `Either` would fit quite well as there is no 'right' error here.

Comment: When I say that `GenericError` is equivalent to `Either ErrorCatA ErrorCatB`, I mean that they're literally isomorphic.  The concept that the `Right` value is "better" than a `Left` value is merely convention, and only really has meaning with the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances for `Either a`.  You don't gain much by writing your own type of two single argument constructors, but you do lose access to many of the functions that exist in libraries for working with and manipulating `Either` values.  You don't have to be using those instances in order to use `Either`.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining. I can see how this works, but I was hoping for a solution that involved a bit less boilerplate code. I still need to implement the instance for every type and create a shadowed version of all possible errors. One of the errors I actually want to wrap is HttpException https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#g:9 which has quite a lot of constructors.

Comment: I'll type up something as an example that could help simplify this somewhat.  It's too long for the comment box.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an existential type.  Look at how the extensible exceptions are done.

Answer (score 8):

Say you have the exception types

```
data HttpException  -- from http-client package
data MyCustomError = WTFError String | OMGError String
data AnotherError = BadError Int | TerribleError Float
```

And you wanted to handle each individually, but generically.  Instead of writing a sum type around them as

```
data AllErrors = A HttpException | B MyCustomError | C AnotherError
```

What you really want is to handle each exception.  So why not just do that?  Write the functions

```
handleHttpError    :: HttpException -> IO ()
handleCustomError  :: MyCustomError -> IO ()
handleAnotherError :: AnotherError  -> IO ()
```

Then write a class

```
class HandledError e where
    handleError :: e -> IO ()
```

With

```
instance HandledError HttpException where
    handleError = handleHttpError

instance HandledError MyCustomError where
    handleError = handleCustomError

instance HandledError AnotherError where
    handleError = handleAnotherError
```

And just use `handleError` where needed.  It isn't really any different than what you have, but now the logic for handling one kind of error isn't mixed in with the logic for handling another kind of error.  Just think of the class level `handleError` as the same as your `handleError . wrap`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I still sometimes think in the OOP way which seems to approach these problems exactly the other way around, that is not in terms of functions but as types or objects that encapsulate some state. I'm going to try and apply this to my application later. Thank you!

Comment: @passy This is something that many Haskellers, including myself, struggle with.  We program in the OOP world so often that it's hard to untrain ourselves to work more with functions and functional program paradigms.  It can be difficult, but always try to really analyze the problem you're trying to solve, and then think of how it can be solved using functions.  The problem here isn't "how to convert errors to a common type", but "how to handle errors in a generic way".  When worded like the latter, it is easier to see that what you want to abstract is the handler, not the error type.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with creating a type class:

```
class GError a where
    errorMessage :: a -> String
```

and provide *meaningful* instances to it:

```
instance GError ErrorCatA where
    errorMessage (WTFError s) = "WTF?! " ++ s
    errorMessage (OMGError s) = "OMG?! " ++ s

instance GError ErrorCatB where
    errorMessage (BadError i)      = "Bad! " ++ show i
    errorMessage (TerribleError f) =  "Terrible! " ++ show f
```

and use it like:

```
handleError :: GError a => a -> IO ()
handleError = putStrLn . errorMessage
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9889e8e784c4c88)

Of course the `GError` instance is fully customizable. You can include any behavior that is both of `ErrorCatA` and `ErrorCatB` in your specific context.

Comment: This sort of works for my example where the errors can be reduced to a simple `Show`. But if there is a more complex error type that I need to inspect than I can't apply this.

Comment: Let's say for example that my `handleError` needs to extract the `Float` value stored in it and react to it accordingly, then I can no longer reduce the error to a simple message. I'll see if I can adjust the example accordingly.

Comment: @passy, in `WTFError String` there's no `Float`. How would it act there?

Comment: Sorry, this is definitely a fault of my contrived example. The main idea is that wrapping and handling the error happens in totally different places, but the handler needs full access to the exception type. Let's say the exception can either be a TimeoutError in which case I'd like to trigger a retry or a NotFoundError in which case I want to abort with an error message.

I changed my example above to handle the `BadError` based on the `i` value to get a bit closer.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf) paper explains how [Control.Exception](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/Control-Exception.html) is implemented. I think it can be called extensible sum-type (a top type for some arbitrary family of (sub-)types, so that "super-type", while a simple sum-type such as `Either a b` is not extensible, but still a super-type for `a` and `b`, a fixed family of subtypes). `Prism`s from the `lens` library are related, see [Control.Lens.Prism](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) and [Control.Exception.Lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Exception-Lens.html) for usage with exceptions.

---

Example with exceptions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Control.Exception

data ErrorCatA = WTFError String | OMGError String deriving ( Show, Typeable )
data ErrorCatB = BadError Int | TerribleError Float deriving ( Show, Typeable )

instance Exception ErrorCatA
instance Exception ErrorCatB

handleError :: SomeException -> IO ()
handleError err =
  putStrLn $ case fromException err of
    Just (WTFError s) -> "WTF?! " ++ s
    Just (OMGError s) -> "OMG?! " ++ s
    _ -> case fromException err of
      Just (BadError i) -> if i > 5 then "Really bad" else "Not that bad"
      Just (TerribleError f) -> "Terrible! " ++ show f
      _ -> "SomeException is extensible, so..."

-- ^ looks not so good, so

data H a = forall e . Exception e => H (e -> a)

match :: SomeException -> b -> [H b] -> b
match e = foldr (\(H f) r -> maybe r f $ fromException e)

-- then

handleError' :: SomeException -> IO ()
handleError' err = putStrLn $ match err handleOther [H handleA, H handleB] where
  handleA (WTFError s) = "WTF?! " ++ s
  handleA (OMGError s) = "OMG?! " ++ s
  handleB (BadError i) = if i > 5 then "Really bad" else "Not that bad"
  handleB (TerribleError f) = "Terrible! " ++ show f
  handleOther = "SomeException is extensible, so..."

-- ^ looks better

main :: IO ()
main = do

  mapM_ (handleError . toException) [WTFError "...", OMGError "..."]
  mapM_ (handleError . toException) [BadError 0, TerribleError 0]
  handleError $ toException DivideByZero

  mapM_ (handleError' . toException) [WTFError "...", OMGError "..."]
  mapM_ (handleError' . toException) [BadError 10, TerribleError 0]
  handleError' $ toException DivideByZero
```

or you can write [`Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Exception.html#Exception)-like class with [`SomeException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Exception.html#SomeException)-like wrapper for your own use (prisms can be added too).